# check if a string starts and ends with ", and add to it if not

Tags: php

I need to check if a string starts and ends with the `"`. And if it is not the case, the `"` should be added to it. e.g. `text` convert into `"text"`. I'm using the folling code for this:

```
if (strpos($owner_text, '"') !== 0)
{
    $owner_text = '"' . $owner_text . '"';
}
```

then I realized, this will not work if I have something like `text"` or `"text`. In these cases, `text"` will be converted into `"text""` and `"text` will stay untouched. So I change the code above:

```
// e.g. text. strpos returns false if nothing found
if (strpos($owner_text, '"') === false && strrpos($owner_text, '"') === false)
{
    $owner_text = '"' . $owner_text . '"';
}
// "text
else if (strpos($owner_text, '"') === 0 && strrpos($owner_text, '"') === 0)
{
    $owner_text = $owner_text . '"';
}

else if (strpos($owner_text, '"') !== 0 && strrpos($owner_text, '"') !== 0)
{
    // text"
    if (strpos($owner_text, '"') == strlen($owner_text) - 1)
    {
        $owner_text = '"' . $owner_text;
    }
    // te"xt
    else
    {
        $owner_text = '"' . $owner_text . '"';
    }
}
```

this works now with `text` `"text` or `text"`, but it seems reaaaally complicated and it has problem with something like `te"xt"`.  How should I do this properly?

Comment: Just check first and last character instead of searching for `"` in the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check first and last character instead of searching for `"` in the whole string:

```
if ($owner_text[0] != '"') $owner_text = '"'.$owner_text;
if ($owner_text[strlen($owner_text)-1] != '"') $owner_text = $owner_text.'"';
```

Note that this code does not do any error checking on `$owner_text`.

**Update** You can even do it with less code (and this also takes care of error handling, e.g. if `$onwer_text` is empty):

```
$owner_text = '"'.trim($owner_text, '"'), '"';
```

Comment: omg, its so easy I should have come up with that myself... was clearly thinking too much...

Comment: @yangsunny I added another, even shorter, method.

Comment: thank you very much. Totally forgot trim not only work for whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might work for you

```
<?php

$str = "yangsunny";

$first = substr($str, 0,1);
$last = substr( $str,-1);
if($first!=='"'){
    $str = '"'.$str;
}
if($last!=='"'){
    $str = $str.'"';
}

echo $str;

?>
```